# *Portable* static blog generators that run on Win7 x64?

Tags: windows-7, portable, static-site-generator

Are there any portable static blog generators that run on Windows 7 x64? I mean ones where you can

- store all files for a blog and all programs required to update it on a flash drive
- connect the flash drive to any computer running Win 7 x64
- update your blog, getting files that you can then FTP to your website

Comment: Did you try some already? Can you try to give more restrictions? There are [soooo](https://staticsitegenerators.net/) many of them (potentially not portable)

Comment: Portable is a key restriction! :-) I haven't found what I'm looking for yet. I've seen that list and also [this one](http://www.staticgen.com) which tags some of the static site generators as good for blogs; and two efforts ([here](https://github.com/madhur/PortableJekyll) and [here](http://www.nickw.it/jekyll-dot-exe/)) at making Jekyll portable, requiring Ruby, but the USB stick might need to get put into a computer which hasn't got Ruby, Python, etc.

Comment: PortableJekyll has a Ruby subdirectory, so maybe it does not need to be installed?

Comment: Otherwise we have a lot of new requirements: no Ruby, no Python, no .NET and no Java.

Comment: I am not sure which of those could be dispensed with and which are indispensable but could be bundled up in the package on the USB stick. I am close to the limit of my present knowledge, but I've done a lot of searching from where it is at the moment and have tried to make the question clear. I'll have a closer look at PortableJekyll.

Answer (score 1):

[WinPython](http://winpython.github.io/) is a portable python toolkit that also allows you to [add packages](https://github.com/winpython/winpython/wiki/Installing-Additional-Packages) to it while keeping it portable.  It can run either from a USB key or from a directory on the hard drive but without actual installation, *(copying is not quite the same as installation)*.

Then you have a wide range of python based blog generators, there is a list of some of them [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonBlogSoftware), but personally I would take a look at [ABlog](http://ablog.readthedocs.org/).

As a test I downloaded the 64 bit version of winpython 3.4.3.5 and installed it to my hard drive the install took up <1.4 GB without ABlog and installing took seconds and didn't make a noticeable difference to the size as most of the dependencies were already met.  N.B. For the most portability I would suggest using the 32 bit version rather than the 64 bit.

ABlog is a Sphinx extension that converts any documentation or personal website project into a full-fledged blog with:

- Atom feeds
- Archive pages
- Blog sidebars
- Disqus integration
- Font-Awesome integration
- Easy GitHub Pages deploys

I did hit a couple of hickups following the tutorial due to non-ascii characters on line 22 of the generated conf.py but since that was a comment deleting it solved the issue.

My First Blog page with ABlog:
[image]

Of course you will now have a full portable version of python & iPython to play with and a suite of scientific tools, graphing, etc. to play with in them!